# Double elements in a list if values are over certain threshold

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Trying to double elements of a list that are greater than 5 for example.

to double every element in a list i would do this

```
doubleAll n = [2*x| x <-n]
```

now i want to double all elements in list that are greater than 5 using list comprehensions.
So if i do this

```
doubleAll n = [2*x| x <-n, x>5]
```

My list [1,2,3,4,5] would  result in to [10]. But i want my list to show [1,2,3,4,10]

Can anyone explain what i did wrong and how can this be fixed?

Comment: A simple repair is `doubleAll n = [if x > 5 then 2*x else x | x <-n]`

Comment: What you did wrong is that placing a boolean condition in a list comprehension simply skips that element if the condition is false, instead of including the element unchanged as you expected it to.

Comment: see now this helps a lot. since i am new to haskell i am not familiar with the syntax. if you can write this as answer i will accept it :) thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interpretation of `[2*x| x <-n, x>5]` is:

1. Take the next element from `n` and call it `x`
2. Proceed if `x>5`, otherwise go to step 1
3. Return the value `2*x` as the next element of the list.
4. Repeat

From this it is clear that the `x>5` filters out elements of `n`. The expression is equivalent to:

```
map (\x -> 2*x) ( filter (\x -> x>5) n )
```

As [Arthur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183792/arthur) mentioned, you want something like:

```
[ if x > 5 then 2*x else x | x <- n ]
```

It's interpretation is:

1. Take the next value of `n` and call it `x`
2. Return the value `if x > 5 then 2*x else x` as then next value of the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearer to understand if you don't use list comprehensions and use the `map` and `filter` operations instead:

```
-- Apply a function to every element of the list.
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]

-- Throw out list elements that don't pass the test.
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

Your original `doubleAll` is equivalent this:

```
-- Multiply every element of the list by two.
doubleAll xs = map (*2) xs
```

The version where you double only if `x > 5` would be this:

```
-- Apply the `step` function to every element of the list.  This step function 
-- multiplies by two if x >= 5, otherwise it just returns its argument.
doubleAll xs = map step xs
    where step x | x >= 5    = 2*x
                 | otherwise = x
```

The problem with the list comprehension version that you wrote is that it's instead equivalent to this:

```
-- Filter out list elements that are smaller than 5, then double the remaining ones.
doubleAll xs = map (*2) (filter (>=5) xs)
```

The list comprehension solution that produces the result you want would instead be this:

```
doubleAll xs = [if x >= 5 then x*2 else x | x <- xs]
```

As a more general remark, I always recommend to newcomers to stay away from list comprehensions and learn the higher-order list functions, which are more general and less magical.